# Is it okay to use an external flash drive to store a Photos Library?

Tags: macos, photos.app, flash-memory

I'm getting an M1 MacBook Pro from my employer which only has 512 GB of flash storage (my 2018 MBP has 1 TB), so I'll need to move my 350 GB Photos library to an external drive. I know that I could have Photos optimize for storage (I do have iCloud Library), but I think it's best to have the full-size Photos library stored somewhere.

Would it be okay to store the Photos library on an external thumb-type flash drive from a reputable manufacturer such as SanDisk, or should I stick to a more conventional external USB flash drive, such as the SanDisk Extreme series?

Comment: You can keep your photo library on an external drive, that's not a problem.  I've done that a few times when I was running low on storage.  An external ssd is your best option.  Do you have any constraints that would impact the answer (cost, size, etc)?

Comment: I've had clients who've lost very important files (not just photos) when the _only_ copies have been on thumb drives. Personally, I use a combo of external SSD drives (rugged LaCie to be precise) as well as redundant cloud storage (DropBox, Google Drive) for the most important stuff **I just can't lose.** _Disclaimer: satisfied customer of LaCie (Seagate) products for over 20 years - no financial or other ties to the company._

Comment: Note that I do have my entire photos library as an iCloud Photo Library, but I understand that it's important to have at least one copy of it on a drive somewhere.

Comment: @fsb: I bought a SanDisk Extreme 1TB SSD. It's pretty small. A good solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is Apple support document [Move your Photos library to save space on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517) where among other things are stated:

> To prevent data loss, Apple doesn't recommend storing photo libraries
> on external storage devices like SD cards and USB flash drives, or
> drives that are shared on a network.

Comment: Yes, but "USB flash drives" isn't terribly clear: an external SSD drive is a USB flash drive, isn't it?